# How to get GETted json data in Flask

Tags: python, json, curl, flask

I am implementing a REST API in Python using Flask.
I have to get parameters to perform a query and return resources. To be aligned with `REST` principles, I am going to use a `GET` request for this operation.

Given that there can be a lot of parameters, I want to send them through a `conf.json` file, for instance:

```
{"parameter": "xxx"}
```

I perform the request through `curl`:

> $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @conf.json -G http://localhost:8080/resources/

The request is redirected to the route with these operations:

```
@resources.route('/resources/', methods=['GET'])
def discover():
if request.get_json():
    json_data=request.get_json()
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

what I get back is:

```
<head> 
<title>Error response</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Error response</h1> 
<p>Error code 400. 
<p>Message: Bad request syntax ('GET /resources/?{"parameter": "xxx"} HTTP/1.1'). 
<p>Error code explanation: 400 = Bad request syntax or unsupported method. </body>
```

Somebody knows how to get the json data and properly handle it in the request?

Comment: @ loads file as url parameter since the request is GET type. This doesn't look very nice and may cause many problems with character encoding. Are you sure this is how you want it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.get_json()` looks for JSON data in the request *body* (e.g. what a POST request would include). You put the JSON data in the *URL query string* of a GET request instead.

Your `curl` command sends your JSON un-escaped, and produces an invalid URL, so the server *rightly* rejects that:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/?{"parameter": "xxx"}
```

You can't have spaces in a URL, for example. You'd have to use `--data-urlencode` instead for this to be escaped properly:

```
$ curl --data-urlencode @conf.json -G http://localhost:8080/resources/
```

Note that the `Content-Type` header is not needed here; you don't have any request body to record the content *of*.

The adjusted `curl` command now sends a properly encoded URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/?%7B%22parameter%22%3A%20%22xxx%22%7D%0A%0A
```

Access that data with `request.query_string`. You will also have to *decode* the URL encoding again before passing this to `json.loads()`:

```
from urllib import unquote

json_raw_data = unquote(request.query_string)
json_data = json.loads(json_raw_data)
```

Take into account that many webservers put limits on how long a URL they'll accept. If you are planning on sending more than 4k characters in a URL this way, you really need to reconsider and use `POST` requests instead. That's 4k with the JSON data *URL encoded*, which adds a considerable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn answer was right with this

```
$ curl --data-urlencode @conf.json -G http://localhost:8080/resources/
```

But you do not need to use `urllib` to get the args with flask. I would instead on my endpoint just use the following.

```
@resources.route('/resources')
def test():
    args = request.args
    return args.get('parameter')
```

Also I would look at using the `flask_testing` extension that way you can setup reproducible test cases that exist within the context of the running application.

```
from flask_testing import TestCase
from app import app

class TestQueryString(TestCase):

    def create_app(self): # Must be implemented
        return app

    def test_json_parse_args(self):
        data = {
            'parameter': 'value'
        }

        r = self.client.get('/resources', query_string=data)
        self.assert200(r)
        self.assertEqual(r.data, 'value')
```

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried but without using `urllib` I cannot get the args. Flask process the `ImmutableMultiDict` in the args like this:

`ImmutableMultiDict([('{"parameter": "xxx"}', u'')])`

instead than:

`ImmutableMultiDict([('parameter': u'xxx')])`

So he doesn't parse the args in the {} I guess

Comment: Yes but the reality is that you are not going to be interacting w/ the API via `curl` in production. You are going to be using a programing language to send the request whether it is JS or Python. Also if you use `-d parameter=value` it will give you the proper query string and would work.